# Rails API - Getting Unpermitted params uploading files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, postman, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to make a POST request to create a restaurant profile uploading two images in each of two attributes(pictures and menus).

I'm using Postman(form-data) to test it and I'm geting `Unpermitted parameters: :pictures, :menus, :format`.

I'll show the code bellow but I want to say that when I use the Strong Parameters like this `params.permit(:name, ..., :pictures, :menus)` , it works but only get one image to each attribute.

Model(restaurant.rb)

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  has_many_attached :pictures
  has_many_attached :menus

end
```

Controller(restaurant_controller.rb)

```
module Api
  module V1
    class RestaurantsController < Api::V1::ApiController

      def create
        @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
        render json: @restaurant, status: :created if @restaurant.save!
      end

      private

      def restaurant_params
        params.permit(
          :name, :status, :address,
          :neighborhood, :city, :phone,
          :other_phone, :cost, :timmings,
          :happy_hour, :coffee, :delivery,
          :ac, :wifi, :cards, :tickets,
          :outside_place, :club, :vegetarian,
          :map, :cuisine_id, :latitude,
          :longitude, pictures: [], menus: []
        )
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Serializer(restaurant_serializer.rb)

```
class RestaurantSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  attributes :id, :name, :pictures, :menus

  def pictures
    arr = []
    if object.pictures.attached?
      object.pictures.each do |picture|
        arr << {
          url: rails_blob_url(picture)
        }
      end
    end
    arr
  end

  def menus
    arr = []
    if object.menus.attached?
      object.menus.each do |menu|
        arr << {
          url: rails_blob_url(menu)
        }
      end
    end
    arr
  end
end
```

Console(rails server + binding.pry)

```rb
    19: def create
 => 20:   binding.pry
    21:   @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
    22:   render json: @restaurant, status: :created if @restaurant.save!
    23: end

[1] pry(#<Api::V1::RestaurantsController>)> restaurant_params
Unpermitted parameters: :pictures, :menus, :format
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Italo's Palace", "status"=>"available", "address"=>"Av. Dr. Arhur, 23", "neighborhood"=>"Copacabana", "city"=>"Santos", "phone"=>"13 3214-1221", "other_phone"=>"13 3232-1290", "cost"=>"59.99", "timmings"=>"Seg-Qui 12h às 22h, Sex-Sáb 11h 0h & Dom 11h às 16h", "happy_hour"=>"Sex 18h às 21h", "coffee"=>"1", "delivery"=>"1", "ac"=>"1", "wifi"=>"1", "cards"=>"1", "tickets"=>"1", "outside_place"=>"1", "club"=>"1", "vegetarian"=>"1", "cuisine_id"=>"1", "latitude"=>"-23.989099", "longitude"=>"-46.299527"} permitted: true>
```

UPDATE:

Postman request header
[image]

Postman request body with response(image's urls should be included in pictures and menus arrays):

[image]

Console:
[image]

Comment: How does your request in Postman actually look like?

Comment: Added pictures @spickermann :)

Comment: if it is 'post' request then postman will take care of multipart so, try using removing content-type: multipart option from header

Comment: Hi @Vishal, when I remove `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>` it does not send any params.

Binding.pry in console:

```ruby
[1] pry(#<Api::V1::RestaurantsController>)> restaurant_params
Unpermitted parameter: :format
=> <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
[2] pry(#<Api::V1::RestaurantsController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/v1/restaurants", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>

```

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to specify the nested attributes inside params definition for example for pictures  `params.permit(pictures:[:src,:name])`

Comment: Same error @Andres Salazar Lopez (pictures: [:src,:name], menus: [:src,:name]) got `Unpermitted parameters: :pictures, :menus, :forma`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on Postman, it was sending only one file.
I fixed adding `[]` after pictures and menus params.
As shown in the picture:
[image]